# Roland-Garros (French Open) public viewing in Paris?

Tags: paris, sports-events

Does anybody know a location that shows the French Open final tomorrow on a big screen in public in Paris?
All the places we found so far where they used to show it in recent years don’t this year (Hotel de Ville, Eifel Tower).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can find, the only big-screen retransmission of Roland-Garros in Paris this year is in Roland-Garros itself. There's a large screen outside the venue. I didn't find anything else with a Google search in French and the [article on the Paris municipality website](https://quefaire.paris.fr/80073/roland-garros) doesn't mention anything. It looks like there's no [*Roland-Garros dans la ville*](https://www.rolandgarros.com/fr-fr/page/roland-garros-dans-la-ville-2018-tour-eiffel) program this year.

Plenty of [bars and cafés](http://ebar.lequipe.fr/matches/Paris/tennis) are showing it on TV.

Tennis is popular in France (well, mostly Roland-Garros), but not as popular as football. This year the [women's football world cup](https://quefaire.paris.fr/80465/coupe-du-monde-feminine-de-la-fifa-programme-des-festivites) is [being held in Paris](https://www.sortiraparis.com/loisirs/sport/guides/193171-coupe-du-monde-feminine-de-football-2019-ou-voir-les-matches-a-paris), so tennis has to compete for attention and organization capacity.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The list of bars is very helpful!

Comment: My wife I are in Paris now, went to Roland Garros one day, and have on other days had no difficulty in finding a sports bar/bar with screens that would happily turn on the French Open.

Comment: @David If that was before Friday, there was no football match competing. Though I don't know what times the matches are, maybe they don't overlap.

Comment: Football seemed to begin on Friday evening; because tennis play ends in the late afternoon, we saw no conflicts. It's now Sunday morning and we're leaving, so I'll have no more reports about where to watch the men's singles final.